# Android Multiple Grid Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

I want to do following things:

1-Create a grid(Size is depend on number of image series) of images on one screen
2-When clicked/chosen a image. 
3-second grid (Size is depend on number of image series) of images will be on screen.
4-Horizontal Swipe the first screen to next one to display the other grid(i.e remaining images)
5-When clicked/chosen a image on last grid, an image or layout will be on screen.

Similar to the Grid we see in our android Phone's

Any answer truly Appreciated...

Comment: You'll have to provide some idea or attempt on how to solve this. There's some stuff you can look up: gridviews and viewpagers (swipe). 
Start somewhere and ask a concrete question with provided code, but at this point your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand this correctly, you are probably thinking of a GridView, which takes an adapter to populate the grid with images, just like an adapter for a ListView populates the list with Textviews (or whatever you have in your custom adapter layout).

As for the support to select an image to go to another grid (subdirectories of images?) and swiping between various grids, this would be done using Fragments. For the subdirectory stuff, I don't know if there is an API somewhere to help with this, but if not you would need to implement a recursive tree structure: the internal nodes would define a point that can be selected to navigate to the next level, and the external nodes would be the individual images. Selecting an internal node would enter that subdirectory, and selecting an external node would open a second Fragment with the larger view of the image.

This is all a bit vague, but hopefully it gives you a place to start looking around. Read the developer docs on GridViews and Fragments to see if they help at all.